# How to access the new x86 bit-manipulation instructions from Common Lisp?

Tags: bit-manipulation, common-lisp, bitwise-operators, sbcl

I want to use the new bit manipulation instructions available in the latest Intel and AMD chips, in particular the "Parallel Bits Extract" `PEXT` instruction (see [here](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PEXT.html) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets)).  How can I access these instructions from within Common Lisp? (specifically SBCL).

Ideally, I would like to access these instructions through a library that detects whether the CPU provides them and, if it doesn't, it emulates them in software.  Compilers for other languages provide such functions (e.g., GCC provides the function `_pext_u32`; see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Built-in-Functions.htmlpext)).

Answer (score 6):

I think that to actually add support for it, you need to modify the compiler itself.  This might involve something like adding a new VOP (see vop.lisp in the sbcl sources) defining a new function that compiles to it (maybe in the sb-ext package) and wiring it up.  I can't actually tell you how to do that, my understanding of that is only superficial.

The other way, which might be more portable, is to create a C library containing functions that use the new primitive in assembly, then to wrap it in a CFFI binding.

Comment: Thank you.  These are interesting approaches but the problem with these is that (a) modifying vop.lisp isn't very portable and CFFI adds overhead (I want to use the PEXT instruction in an inner loop that runs billions of times).  It wold be ideal if SBCL allowed for inline assembly code.

Comment: I think I just found a viable approach here: https://www.pvk.ca/Blog/2014/08/16/how-to-define-new-intrinsics-in-sbcl/

Answer (score 3):

There's a variable (at least in CMU Common Lisp, of which Steel Bank is a fork of) called `*features*` that lists some information about the system Lisp is running on. Mine looks like this:

```
(:GERDS-PCL :PCL-STRUCTURES :PORTABLE-COMMONLOOPS :PCL :CMU21 :CMU21B :PYTHON
 :MODULAR-ARITH :MP :X86 :RELOCATABLE-STACKS :SSE2 :LINKAGE-TABLE
 :RELATIVE-PACKAGE-NAMES :EXECUTABLE :MACH-O :DARWIN :BSD :UNIX :RANDOM-MT19937
 :GENCGC :CMUCL :UNICODE :COMPLEX-FP-VOPS :HASH-NEW :ALIEN-CALLBACK
 :DOUBLE-DOUBLE :HEAP-OVERFLOW-CHECK :STACK-CHECKING :COMMON-LISP :ANSI-CL
 :IEEE-FLOATING-POINT :CMU)
```

That might tell you what you need to know. If not, try looking for something with `(apropos 'feature)`, and that should display a list of symbols with "feature" in them.

Comment: SBCL has this variable, indeed, but it doesn't seem to show CPU capabilities (e.g., in my output there's no SSE2).  In any case, knowing the CPU features is useful, but it does not answer the question (which is about how to call a given CPU instruction from Common Lisp).

Comment: *features* really only tell you what compiler and library support you have available at the time of looking at the list.